# GCP: Add cloud function in front of cloudfront to serve video

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Right now, I have a cloudfront distribution that serves video from our S3 as the origin. Any call for video from our website goes to cloudfront that serves video either from cache or S3 depending on cache policy. Now, I want to add a cloud function in front of cloudfront. All requests will be coming to cloudfunction first, and then it would be a small axios code to make the call to cloudfront and pipe the cloudfront response to cloudfunction response. Following is the code snippet -

```
const appendCFHeaders = (res, responseHeaders = {}) => {
  Object.keys(responseHeaders).forEach((headerKey) => {
    res.set(`X-SDCF-${headerKey}`, responseHeaders[headerKey]);
  })
}

const appendContentTypeHeader = (res, responseHeaders = {}) => {
  res.set(`Content-Type`, responseHeaders['content-type'] || "video/webm");
}

app.get('/*', async (req, res) => {

  try {
    postToSlack({ request_headers: JSON.stringify(req.headers) }, 'VC Init');
    const urlToFetch = `${APP_CONSTANTS.CLOUDFRONT_URL}${req.url}`;
    const config = {
      method: 'get',
      responseType: 'stream',
      url: urlToFetch,
      headers: {
        ...req.headers,
        host: APP_CONSTANTS.CLOUDFRONT_HOST,
      }
    }
    axios(config).then(response => {
      postToSlack({ url: urlToFetch, website: req.headers['referer'], request_headers: JSON.stringify(req.headers), response_headers: JSON.stringify(response.headers) }, 'CF Response 200');
      appendCFHeaders(res, response.headers);
      appendContentTypeHeader(res, response.headers);
      response.data.pipe(res);
    }).catch(err => {
      if(err.response) {
        const responseStatusCode = err.response.status;
        postToSlack({ url: urlToFetch, website: req.headers['referer'], request_headers: JSON.stringify(req.headers), response_headers: JSON.stringify(err.response.headers) }, 'CF Response Non200');
        if(err.response.data) {
          appendCFHeaders(res, err.response.headers);
          appendContentTypeHeader(res, err.response.headers);
          err.response.data.pipe(res);
        } else {
          appendCFHeaders(res, err.response.headers);
          appendContentTypeHeader(res, err.response.headers);
          res.status(responseStatusCode).send(err.response.data);
        }
        return;
      }
      postToSlack({ url: urlToFetch, website: req.headers['referer'], request_headers: JSON.stringify(req.headers), response_headers: JSON.stringify(err.response.headers) }, 'CF Response 500');
      appendContentTypeHeader(res, {})
      return res.status(500).send(null);
    })
   
  } catch(err) {
    res.status(500).send(`some error: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
  }
});
```

This code works, but have ran into a bug/issue. If I seek the video in the HTML5 video, browser sends a request for new video part, and weirdly, it stops playing. My initial guess is that with different Range header, google CDN is caching 'wrong' response against wrong 'header', but have no clue how to solve this. Any help is appreciated.